# How to simplify the following integral to be in terms of Bessel functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I have evaluated the following integration using Mathematica. I obtained a solution in terms of Meijer G function. I wonder if it can be simplified to be in terms of Bessel functions.

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  x Exp[-θ x^2/(
     4 t) ] (BesselJ[0, λ x] BesselY[0, λ] - 
     BesselY[0, λ x] BesselJ[0, λ]), {x, 0, 
   Infinity}]]
```

```
(2 t (E^(-((t λ^2)/θ)) BesselY[0, λ] - 
   BesselJ[0, λ] MeijerG[{{0}, {-(1/2)}}, {{0, 
       0}, {-(1/2)}}, (t λ^2)/θ]))/θ
```

Comment: Have you tried using `FunctionExpand[]` on it?

Comment: Yes. I have. But it doesn't simplify it.

Comment: Then it looks like *Mathematica* is unaware if the $G$-function has a further simplification, if it does have one.

Comment: What constraints/assumptions, if any, exist for parameters `theta`, `lambda`, and `t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your Meijer G function is equal to $\frac{e^{-z}\operatorname{Ei}(z)}{\pi}$. I cannot prove it except plotting their difference to ridiculous precision, and referring to [this similar-looking identity on the Wolfram Functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/04/15/0002/):

```
g[z_] = MeijerG[{{0}, {-(1/2)}}, {{0, 0}, {-(1/2)}}, z];
h[z_] = E^(-z) * ExpIntegralEi[z] / π;

Plot[g[z] - h[z], {z, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 10^4]
```

[image]

Comment: Evaluating `DifferentialRootReduce[MeijerG[{{0}, {-1/2}}, {{0, 0}, {-1/2}}, z] - Exp[-z] ExpIntegralEi[z]/Pi, z]` yields a 4th-order ODE with all initial conditions equal to 0, so...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I reached to the same result by substituting numerical values for theta, lamda, and t. Thanks again. @Roman